# RGB to HEX Conversion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a JSFiddle of a HEX to RGB conversion but I'm wondering how I can do it the other way (RGB to HEX).

```
$('#hex').bind('blur keydown', function (event) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var rgb = [],
        broken = false,
        value = $("#hex").val(),
        hex = (value+'').replace(/#/, '');

    if (value.length === 1 && value !== '#') {
      $("#hex").val(value);
    }

    if (hex.length == 3) hex = hex + hex;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i+=2) {
      rgb.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i,2),16));
      broken = broken || rgb[rgb.length - 1].toString() === 'NaN';
    }

    $('#rgb').val(broken ? '' : 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')');   
  }, 13);
});
```

`'#hex'` and `'#rgb'` are just inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="hex" placeholder="hex">
<input type="text" id="rgb" placeholder="rgb">
```

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gFvgD/)

I'm also wondering why if I was to replace `broken` with `false`, I get an error. Do you know why I can't remove `var broken = false` and just replace with `false`?

Comment: Remark: Your logic is currently wrong. `#abc` isn't `#abcabc` but `#aabbcc`.

Comment: Oh, is it? How can I fix that? Sorry, I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5623838/989121

Comment: I don't know JavaScript so it doesn't really help :/

Comment: @user2203362: If you're new to JavaScript and don't understand something, search for it. Usually you will get links to https://developer.mozilla.org/, which is a great resource for beginners.

Comment: @user2203362 You don't need to wrap event handler with `setTimeout` if you bind to `keyup` instead of `keydown` event.

Comment: Oh, so I should just remove that then?

Comment: @Vadim When I remove `setTimeout` it doesn't update `#rgb` unless I hit enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that will convert RGB to HEX:

```
$(function(){
  var $hex = $('#hex');
  $('#rgb').on('keyup blur', function() {
    var value = this.value,
        rgb,
        hex = '',
        component,
        i;
    try {
      if(value && value.indexOf('rgb(') === 0 && value[value.length-1] === ')') {
        rgb = value.slice(4,-1).split(',');
        if(rgb.length === 3) {
          for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            if(rgb[i] <= 0xFF) {
              component = parseInt(rgb[i],10);
              if(isNaN(component)) {
                throw new SyntaxError();
              }
              component = component.toString(16);
              if(component.length === 1) {
                component = '0'+component;
              }
              hex += component;
            } else {
              throw new RangeError();
            }
          }
          $hex.val('#'+hex);
        } else {
          throw new SyntaxError();
        }
      }
    } catch(e) {
      $hex.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

An here is working example http://jsbin.com/amisen/3/edit

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Do you know what the problem is with my HEX to RGB? Apparently the logic is wrong.

Comment: @user2203362 You should replace `if (hex.length == 3) hex = hex + hex;` with `if (hex.length === 3) hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];`

Comment: In the RGB to HEX, is there a way it can display the shorter version  e.g. `#444` instead of `#444444` or is that not possible?